# How do i access inner Text of Div tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="main_box">
  <div class="div_r">
    <div class="div_l">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('main_box').childNodes[1].innerHTML);
</script>
```

I want to get inner content of "div_l" class with reference to "main_box" class.
I have tried above code but its not working.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('main_box')[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML
```

Comment: nope its not working and gives error "cannot read property childNodes of undefined"

Comment: @PoojaDesai I've corrected the example. It has to be childNode with index 1. Then it works, still the document.querySelectorAll would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('main_box')[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML
                                                 ^^^--
```

you need to tell WHICH node to get the child of, since gEBCN() returns a node **LIST**, not just a single node.

Comment: nope its not working and gives error "cannot read property childNodes of undefined"

Comment: @PoojaDesai You are wrong, it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/pLXrs/ might have another problem here?

Answer (score 0):

What about using jQuery?

**Example :**

```
var value = $('.main_box .div_r .div_l').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

In [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('.main_box .div_l').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different variants to reach this. As already answered you could use getElementsByClassName, only thing you missed is that this function returns an array.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('main_box')....
```

A newer syntax (not supported by ie < 9) is:

a) in case you expect more than one element:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.main_box .div_r .div_l')[0].innerHTML
```

b) in case you expect max one one:

```
 document.querySelector('.main_box .div_r .div_l').innerHTML
```